# Android: on low battery BroadcastReceiver is triggered after application killing

Tags: java, android, singleton

In short, my application is a service that sends data to the server with the location of the device.

I got a singleton class as below:

```
public class LocationHelper implements LocationListener {
    private Location mLocation = null;

    public static LocationHelper getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    static class SingletonHolder {
        static LocationHelper INSTANCE = new LocationHelper(App.getContext());
    }

    private LocationHelper(final Context context) {
        if (!checkLocationPermissionGranted(context)) {
            return;
        }

        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (mLocation == null) mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (mLocation == null) mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
    }

    public void attachLocationUpdates(final Activity activity) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        if (isBetterLocation(location)) mLocation = location;
    }
}
```

I have an alarm as below:

```
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, NetworkSyncReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE_SYNC, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
    final AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now + DELAY_FIVE_MINUTES, DEFAULT_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

I notice that if the device is running low on battery, it already kills the app (which kills the singleton LocationHelper class) and then triggers an alarm.

Shortly before the device dies, my BroadcastReceiver is received, but the location is already empty. The LocationHelper class was killed and is reinitialized and getLastKnownLocation does not provide a location.

How can I change the approach to have valid location on BroadcastReceiver before device dead?